# Uncaught : TypeError: Cannot read property 'featured_src' of undefined

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, woocommerce, ionic3

When I write

```
console.log(JSON.parse(data.body))
```

I got an array of products with their values, but when I want to use it in my ionic application, I get the following error

> HomePage.html:10 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'featured_src' of undefined

This is my **home.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import * as WC from 'woocommerce-api';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

WooCommerce: any;
products: any[];
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.WooCommerce = WC({

      url:"http://localhost/wordpress/",
      consumerKey: "ck_f55351d5b3fa3c6f20620c3f58852be0965260e5",
      consumerSecret:"cs_e2dd57948e51cd2c1997e8952dabd82770378844"
    });
    this.WooCommerce.getAsync("products").then((data)=> {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data.body).products[0].title);
      this.products = JSON.parse(data.body).products;

    },(err) =>{
      console.log(err)
    })
  }

}
```

This is my **home.html**:

```
    <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <ion-card>
  <ion-slides autoplay="3000" pager>
    <ion-slide *ngFor ="let number of [1,2,1,2]">
      <img src="./assets/images/{{number}}.jpg" alt="" width="200px" height="150px">
    </ion-slide>

  </ion-slides>
</ion-card>
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-slides>
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let product of products"></ion-slide>
      <ion-card no-padding>
        <img [src]="product.featured_src">
        <h1>{{product.title}}</h1>
        <p>{{product.short_description}}</p>
      </ion-card>
    </ion-slides>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your api response is asynchronous , use safe navigation operator,

```
 <img [src]="product?.featured_src">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i dont have that error, by still dont work propertly. I got the array of products in console, but again i have an error: "GET http://localhost:8100/null 404 (Not Found)". localhost:8100 is localhost for ionic app.

Comment: When i remove img tag, and just let h1 and p tag, i got no errors, but still dont display title and description from products array.

Comment: you do not have to parse, try  this.products = data.body.products;

Comment: Still got no data on app

Comment: Also i tried to see what happens when i change to console.log(data.body.products) and i got result undefined, but with json.parse i got on console array of products

Comment: Maybe it is problem with cors issue, i also had that issue and i solve it with installation of cors plugin on google chrome.